# Counting lines within tabulary

Tags: line-numbering, tabulary, lineno, linenumber

I am trying to add line numbers to an `article` that I am writing, using the `lineno` package. For the most part this works well, except for tables (using `tabulary`): Counting the whole table as a single line works, but when I use `edtable.sty` (part of `lineno`) it seems to skip a few lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[edtable]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. \verb+\lineno+ will skip 2 lines:

\vspace{2em}\begin{edtable}{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LR}
This sentence no verb. &  \\\hline
I would like to know: & Where are the missing two lines? \\\hline
\end{edtable}\vspace{2em}

And now without \verb+edtable+:

\vspace{2em}\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{RL}
The table will be counted & as a single line. \\\hline
Regardless & of \\\hline
actual & length \\\hline
\end{tabulary}\vspace{2em}

This concludes our demonstration.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Can I, perhaps, decrease the line counter manually? I use the `pagewise` option and only have a few tables, so that would be an acceptable workaround. Or some other package?

**Edit:**

Following a suggestion by David, I tried to store the current `linenumber` in a counter, and reset to this counter within `tabulary`, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[edtable]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\newcounter{myfoo}\setcounter{myfoo}{\value{linenumber}}

\begin{edtable}{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LR}
\setcounter{linenumber}{\value{myfoo}}
The counter reset kicks in & too late, though. \\\hline
Notice line numbers & 1-4-reset-3\\\hline
\end{edtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

At this time it's already too late though, an incorrect linenumber has already been writen. Is there any way to have the reset earlier, yet within `tabularray`? My attempts with `\AtBeginEnvironment` have not been successful.

Comment: Playing around with counters, `\addtocounter{linenumber}{-2}` seems to "work", as a quick & dirty and downright ugly fix. The amount of lines skipped is not identical, though, and I still have no idea what causes it.

Comment: well ty runs code multiple times, save the value of linenumber before the table then set it to that at the start so it gets reset every trial

Comment: Unfortunately a counter reset seems to come too late for this scenario … (See my changes above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the counter back at the end of a trial run (which you can detect as display math is inline in trials)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[edtable]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\newcounter{myfoo}\setcounter{myfoo}{\numexpr\value{linenumber}-1}

\begin{edtable}{tabulary}{\linewidth}{LR}
The counter reset kicks in & too late, though. \\\hline
Notice line numbers & 1-4-reset-3%
\ifx\equation$\setcounter{linenumber}{\value{myfoo}}\fi
\\\hline
\end{edtable}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tested this approach thoroughly, and it works fine.